# Fast alternative to find out locations of an array using ismember in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting, signal-processing

I have an array A.

```
 A = [1 0 1 4.3 4.5 5 4.3 3 0 0 0 2 6.2 6.3 7 6.2 7.4 8  7.2 1 2 3 4 2];
```

Positive and Negative Local maximas and minimas.

```
Ypos =[  5     7     8     4]
Yposloc = [6    15    18    23  ]
Yneg   = [     0         0    6.2000    1.0000 ]
Ynegloc = [2     9    16    20 ]
```

Now I combined all maximas and minimas in one array

```
Y = [0    5.0000         0    7.0000    6.2000    8.0000    1.0000    4.0000]
Yloc = [2     6     9  13  15    18    20    23]
```

Then I applied filter and removed some maximas and minimas and separted local maximas and minimas with removed locations

```
Ylocknew = [0    5.0000         0    7.0000       8.0000    1.0000    4.0000]
Yloc = [2     6     9    15    18    20    23]
```

Or simply is there any way to find out Locations of these filtered values in original arrays.

After separation of local maximas and minimas I got these arrays

```
Yposnew = [    5     7     8     4]
Ynegnew = [   0     0     1]
```

**Question.**

I need to ask is there any fast way to find location of  `Yposnew` and `Ynegnew` in original array `A` instead of loop as loop is taking a lot of time.

(Please consider that In my original data I have elements that are repeating so I need those.)

Please have a look at code.

```
 A = [1 0 1 4.3 4.5 5 4.3 3 0 0 0 2 6.2 6.3 7 6.2 7.4 8  7.2 1 2 3 4 2];
 t= 1:numel(A);
 X=A;
[Ypos,Yposloc] = findpeaks(X);
[Yneg,Ynegloc] = findpeaks(-X);
Yneg = -1*Yneg;
Y = zeros(1, max([Yposloc, Ynegloc]));
Yloc = zeros(size(Y));
Yloc(Yposloc) = Yposloc;
Yloc(Ynegloc) = Ynegloc;
Y(Yposloc) = Ypos; 
Y(Ynegloc) = Yneg;

Y = Y(Yloc ~= 0) % this is the combined signal what I am expecting
Yloc = Yloc(Yloc ~= 0) % this is the combined locations what i am expecting

% I have applied limits on combined local maxima and minima array 

for i = 1:numel(Y)-1
%     if  (Y(i+1)<=-6 && Y(i+1)>=8)
    if  (Y(i+1)>= (Y(i)-1) && Y(i+1)<=(Y(i)+1))
%             if  (Y(i+1)<=-1 || Y(i+1)>=1)
    Y(i+1)= inf;

  else 
    Y(i)= Y(i);
  end
%      i=i+1;
  end
 Ylocknew = Y;

 % I have calculated Filtered locations for filtered local maximas array
 for b = 1:numel(Yloc)
 if (Ylocknew(1,b) == inf)
    Yloc(1,b) = inf;
else
    Yloc(1,b) = Yloc(1,b);


end
  b=b+1;

end

 Yloc(Yloc==inf)= []
 Ylocknew(Ylocknew==inf)= []


% I have separated positive and negative local maximas from limited array 

[Yposnew] = Ypos(ismember(Ypos, Ylocknew ));
[Ynegnew] = Yneg(ismember(Yneg, Ylocknew ));
```

**Need a fast alternative or fast way to calculate Locations of filtered local maximas and minimas in original arrays.**

```
% Filtered Locations for FIltered positive local maximas

 for c = 1:numel(Yposnew)
     if (Yposnew(c) == X(Yposloc(c)))
         Yposlocfiltered(c)= Yposloc(c);
     elseif (Yposnew(c) ~= X(Yposloc(c)))
         d=c;
         while(Yposnew(c) ~= X(Yposloc(d)))
               d= c+1;             
         end
              Yposlocfiltered(c)= Yposloc(d);
     end
 end

  % Filtered Locations for Filtered negative local maximas

  for r = 1:numel(Ynegnew)
     if (Ynegnew(r) == X(Ynegloc(r)))
         Yneglocfiltered(r)= Ynegloc(r);
     elseif (Ynegnew(r) ~= X(Ynegloc(r)))
         s=r;
         while(Ynegnew(r) ~= X(Ynegloc(s)))
               s= r+1;             
         end
              Yneglocfiltered(r)= Ynegloc(s);
     end
 end
```

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and ask *one* ***specific*** question.

Comment: Thanks a lot beaker Actually this code is an example that i tried to made for elaboration of my idea what i want to do. I have updated and tried to convey  my message in congested words . Please just have a look at it .

Comment: When you removed the minima/maxima, why did you not also remove their indices in the location arrays?

Comment: Sorry I have tried to remove it in  Yloc  it contains values of filtered locations for filtered local maximas

Comment: You're going to make me read through your 12 previous questions to find out how you did that, aren't you... ;)

Comment: Sorry I have tried to update some more values I have removed 6.2 maxima and its location 13 . You can have a look at Yloc in updated question . Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156941/discussion-between-beaker-and-peter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you step back and look at the information you're getting from the intermediate results of `ismember`, you've already got the indices of the correct locations:

Variable values just before the `ismember` lines:

```
Ypos =[5 7 8 4]
Yposloc = [6 15 18 23]
Yneg = [0 0 6.2000 1.0000]
Ynegloc = [2 9 16 20]
Ylocknew = [0 5.0000 0 7.0000 8.0000 1.0000 4.0000]
Yloc = [2 6 9 15 18 20 23]
```

Now, rather than using the logical indices returned by `ismember` and then throwing them away, we can save them and use them twice:

```
posidx = ismember(Ypos, Ylocknew);   % get locations of Ylocknew in Ypos
% posidx = [1  1  1  1]; keep all Ypos values
Yposnew = Ypos(posidx);         % save the values...
Yposlocnew = Yposloc(posidx);   % and save their corresponding locations

negidx = ismember(Yneg, Ylocknew);   % repeat for Yneg
% negidx = [1  1  0  1]; we've removed Yneg(3)
Ynegnew = Yneg(negidx);              % saving values...
Yneglocnew = Ynegloc(negidx);        % and locations
```

Results:

```
Yposnew = [5 7 8 4]
Yposlocnew = [6 15 18 23]
Ynegnew = [0 0 1]
Yneglocnew = [2 9 20]
```